# query with non Latin characters gives error or stuck mysql 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Our DB was upgraded from `mysql 5.5` to `mysql 5.6`, properties are the same (encoding and such, that is what I am told)
A query with non latin characters that worked fine on mysql 5.5 now fails and issues a `1064`Error

Or the phpMyadmin gets stuck loading...

```
SELECT *
FROM search_1
WHERE  pair_type="pair_one" 
AND ( symbol LIKE 'Евро%'  OR (pair_name_trans) LIKE ('Евро%'))
ORDER BY orders DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

Searching for just the symbol `LIKE 'Евро%'` also works fine.

Any ideas?

(already tried to SET NAMES) tnx.

Comment: You are probably not setting the connection encoding and relying on default value. Now default value has changed. (*already tried to SET NAMES* does not suggest you understand what it's about.)

Comment: I am not sure this has anything to do with the connection encoding since this happens when I run the query in the phpmyadmin as well